# glmulti stability assurance

Tags: r, glm, evolutionary-algorithm

If I were training a neural network, working with k-means, or other machine learning tools, then I would re-run my training with random initial conditions for several reasons including:

- convincing myself that the converged model was a global optimal and not just a local optimum
- to get a sense of the bounds of the radius of convergence.
- to use convergence rates to tell me about "how rough the terrain is"

So I am using the evolutionary algorithm in the R library "glmulti" and I am running into convergence issues.

Background:
I am repeatedly running "glmulti" against ~500 groups of data to find meaningful relationships.  I can't share source code because what I am working on is internally proprietary.

I based what I was doing off of example code provided by [Noam Ross](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/2/20/model-selection-drug.html).

Pseudo-code:

```
my_glmulti <- glmulti(preset_my_glm, #initialize with glm model per Noam Ross
                      level = 2, #type of interactions glmulti looks for
                      crit="aicc", #use sample size appropriate AIC for criteria
                      method = "g", #use genetic algorithm for search
                      plotty =  FALSE, #no plot needed
                      maxsize = 1000 #use 1000 samples (stability?)
                      )
```

Now I get errors where mean criterion = Inf, = NaN, repeatedly.  Sometimes when I restart they "go away".  To me this looks like an initial conditions problem.

Example Error:

```
"Error in if (length(leCrit) == confsetsize && minouN - minou >= - deltaM &&:
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

This is not my code.  I just called "glmulti" so I am guessing it is internal.

Questions:

- are there switches, or wrappers that add re-testing to the glmulti tool?  If so what are they?  I looked through the help page ([link](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/glmulti/docs/glmulti)) but did not see any obvious solution.
- What are the typical criteria that cause the "glmulti" to exit with "inf" or "nan" when a re-run will converge to a consistent solution?  Are there dials that should be activated here?  Is there an "ignore.na =TRUE" somewhere?

Note:
When I google search for the error I get a single link to another (unanswered) stackoverflow question.  ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/error-when-using-glmulti-with-aicc))

Comment: This sounds more like a methods question and more suitable for CrossValidated.com

Comment: Every time I ask about r-packages there, they send me here.  I tried to save them the effort this time around.  I'm familiar with the mathematics behind the learning, but what I am looking for here is package/language specific.

Comment: You are asking for explanations about statistical methods and offering no code and not even any output. So perhaps a statistical/machine-learning audience would not be able to help you either. Maybe I should have voted to close on the basis of vagueness?

Comment: @BondedDust - better now?